# Can I remote debugging on webviews embedded in android apps?

Tags: android, webview, remote-debugging

I've known that we could remote debugging Chrome on Android. But how about webviews in an application? Is there anything to do it?

Comment: Seems you can't invoke remote debug if you're using Android webkit engine. Unless you're working on Android 4.4, which switches to chromium webkit as the WebView engine.

Answer (score 0):

try weinry. It allows you to debug webviews even before Kitkat.